# How can I make this PHP code more efficient? (Editing a line in a CSV file)

Tags: php, csv

This code works, but I just hacked it together with my limited knowledge of PHP and I'm sure there's a more elegant and efficient way to go about it. If you'd be so kind as to point out how I can improve, that would be great!

So I have a CSV file, structured like so:

```
Code        Class     Value    Status      Date Created    Date Redeemed
========================================================================
a51f3g45    gold      50       valid       2012-08-20      
4f6a2984    silver    200      redeemed    2012-08-23      2012-08-27      
gf3eb54b    gold      150      valid       2012-08-30      

etc...
```

The user fills out a form to change the **Class**, **Value**, and **Status** fields of a given line. I cobbled together the following code to replace the old values with the new ones:

```
$file = 'codes.csv';
$old_csv_string = file_get_contents($file);

preg_match('/('.$_POST['code'].',.*,.*,.*,.*,.*)\n/',$old_csv_string,$matches);
$old_row = $matches[1];

preg_match('/'.$_POST['code'].',(.*,.*,.*),.*,.*\n/',$old_csv_string,$matches_part);
$old_row_part = $matches_part[1];

$new_row_part = $_POST['class'].",".$_POST['value'].",".$_POST['status'];
$new_row = str_replace($old_row_part,$new_row_part,$old_row);
$new_csv_string = str_replace($old_row,$new_row,$old_csv_string);
file_put_contents($file,$new_csv_string);
```

So can I do better than 10 lines of code? Any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

*Note: I tried using `fgetcsv`, but I couldn't figure out how to find the unique code within a 2D array, then replace its siblings.*

Comment: How big is the CSV file?  Would it be an option to simply write the whole file again?  That would save you those regexes...

Comment: Is it a formatted file like that (without heading and ====, of course) or you formatted it? If it is not formatted then what delimits fields? A space, spaces, or a tab? For if it is a single character then you can split each line.

Comment: I doubt it'll get longer than 100 lines. But the form only submits info for one of the lines - how do I do the find/replace without regex?

Comment: @Grzegorz I just made it look pretty. It's comma delimited, with a header row.

Comment: Using CSV as a database will lead to problems.  SQLite would be a more appropriate solution.

Comment: I strongly agree with @FrankFarmer +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you doing this ?
I think you should store the data in a SQL table.
Each time user update data, do it in the table.
If you want the CSV to be downloadable at any moment. Use a .htaccess to redirect your.csv to csv_generator.php only if your.csv does not exist.
csv_generator.php will regenerate the whole csv if it does not exist, save it on hard drive for later use, and send it with correct mime/type in header (so it's transparent for user). User don't see he is requesting a php page.
Then you need to delete the csv on hard drive each time someone update the data (so it will be regenerated on next request)

I think this is the way to have an always ready to download csv online.

Do you know google doc does this ? Users can change data in a spreadsheet wich is available to download as a csv from a url (you need to publish this spreadsheet as a csv file).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. This is the day I finally make the jump from unencrypted flat files to SQLite :)

Comment: Glad to help you on that. Doing this is a really good exercise and will make you touch lot of usefull aspects of PHP (database, writing files, .htaccess redirection, headers...)

Answer (score 1):

Try using split like that for each line:

```
list($code, $class, $value, $status, $created, $redeemed) = split(",", $line, 6) ;
```

Thus you will have each field in separate variable.
Of course you need to take care of the first row in case you don't want to copy header.

Comment: This will break on quoted fields containing `,` in the value.  CSV can also contain newlines in fields.  Using a proper CSV parser is preferable to hacking something naive together.

Comment: Agree, however the data shown above does not indicate these problems. I absolutelly agree with you that for general purpose csv files a parser is the right solution.